# Request.AnonymousId resetting intermittently

Tags: asp.net

I have an app that uses the ASP.NET Request.AnonymousId to save/load a user context for unauthenticated users.  The app is a 4.8 MVC app and it runs on Azure.  It appears that intermittently, user information is dropping and it seems to be related to a new AnonymousId being generated.  The cookie timeout is 100,000 minutes, 2.5 months and it's highly unlikely a cookie expiration because of the (in)convenient timing.  Because it's in an Azure AppService plan that scales, I doubt it's a mismatched machine key, but I'm not certain.

1. What else could this be?
2. I use NLog to log to AppInsights, is there a way to get cookie validation errors logged to rule out the machine key issue?  I haven't been able to location an event

Comment: Are you allowing your users to log in?

Comment: Yes, but they are checking out anonymously here.  Their data follows them if they logged in vs anonymous.

Comment: I doubt it's the ASP.NET infrastructure. My educated guess is something on the user's device is clearing or hiding the cookie. You could try using the [AnonymousIdentification_Creating event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.anonymousidentificationmodule.creating?view=netframework-4.8) to bootstrap and log the creation of new ids and get some insights.